# How do I move items freely in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to editing web pages on ASP.NET webforms and is currently exploring, whenever I add items, they are always added on top left and I can't move it to center, I just want my button to be at center.
I'll use my website for school purposes only and most likely will be disposed after some 2 years, that's why I used webforms instead of MVC because this is a short-lived project

How do I move it freely?

Comment: Web pages is a different "paradigm". Usually you use something like bootstrap to lay out your page. Also if your starting web page programming, I suggest you learn MVC, not webforms.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid does MVC has drag and drop? I'm having troubles designing without drag and drop

Comment: When you create Web pages (any technology), you will need to learn some html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean, however, I will try and provide a solution.
[image]

Unfortunately, because of a bug, the menu is disabled for  and  based controls. To enable the menu, add style=”display:block” to labels or hyperlinks. This will be fixed in the next service pack. You can then use the Position dialog to set positioning mode:

[image]

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/absolute-and-relative-positioning-in-visual-web-developer-2008-designer/

this is a good website to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `.aspx Source` page and modify the control's style like this:

```
style="position:absolute; top: ...; left: ...;"
```

Now you can drag it to anywhere you want. But setting the position of the control programmatically is a better choice.